# AFNetworking get JSON after 404 Bad Request still getting a JSON response

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

I have a Django Rest Api with a iOS app and right now I'm testing AFNetworking to change the HTTP Request my app is doing but i came with this dilema that i dont know how to handle, first is that on REST Standards when i get an error i should return a 404_BAD_REQUEST as a status if either sends or something wrong happens and this is OK. The issue comes when AFNetworking sees this 404. I still want to see the JSON that it returns.

```
curl -X POST http://domain.com:8000/user-login/ -d "nick=superUser&pass_field=superPassword"
```

i get 202 Status HTTP:

```
{
 "nick": "eddwinpaz", "rate": 30, "name": "Eddwin Paz", "avatar": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t1.0-1/p160x160/10270540_10154074250190063_1762683854515424400_n.jpg", "id": 9}eddwinpazs-MacBook-Pro:~ eddwinpaz$ 
}
```

When i get 404 BAD REQUEST i get:

```
{"message": "Invalid Username or Password"}
```

I want to grab that message json tag if i get a 404 Error

I've the following code. and put it on the message on the Alert

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"nick": @"eddwinpaz",@"pass_field":@"eddwinpaz1"};

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@"http://domain.com/user-login/"];
[operation addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:404]];

[manager POST:@"http://domain.com/user-login/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                                                         message:@"E-mail or password are wrong, Please Try Again"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         [hud hide:YES];

     }];
```

Comment: Isn't that message in your NSError? Like [error userInfo]?

Comment: If i use the message:[error localizedDescription] only see 404 BAD REQUEST but the response still shows what went wrong with the request. example above {"message":"Invalid Username or Password"}

Comment: Ok, I don't understand what you'd like to do. Add the response you get for these two lines: *[error localizedDescription]* *[error code]*. Then add what you'd expect to get.

Comment: FYI - it's a 400 (bad request) error, not a 404 (page not found) error.

Comment: @eddwinpaz How did you manage this issue? I'm having same issue, please share. Thanks

Comment: I listen to the error code, check this out this is the code fixed. https://github.com/eddwinpaz/textveloper-swift-ios/blob/master/textveloper/ViewController.swift hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Per default the error code 404 is handled as an error code. You could add it as one of the accepted error codes via

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@"http://doma...
[operation addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:404]];
```

Then `success:` is called on an 404 response and you can handle it there.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but where do i add this line of code? Thanks.

Comment: '[manager POST:' returns an 'AFNetworkingOperation *operation = ...'.

Comment: I've added it like this and still addAcceptableStatusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:404];
    
    [manager POST:@"http://domain.com/user-login/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but can you explain how to define operation using my code??? thanks. I know it will add 404 to the list as accepted code but still dont know where to add this line and what operation variable is getting from.

Comment: I've added one more line of code to the answer, hope you get it know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @miho did not work for me. `addAcceptableStatusCodes` does not exist in AFNetworking 2.5.0 from what I can tell. I had to do the following.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *acceptedCodes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]
    initWithIndexSet:operation.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes];
[acceptedCodes addIndex:304];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [acceptedCodes copy];
```